# How do I navigate to a dynamic page with React Router from a list of elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've rendered a list from an API and have it displayed, and I'd like to make each one clickable and go to a new URL for that item. I've added Route to the App component for some reason because I thought it would switch the page. I assume  does that but it just changes the url in the and the page remains the same.

The main App component:

```
   function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Route path="/">
            {" "}
            <HomePage />{" "}
          </Route>
    
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/:id" children={<SelectedPokemon />}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }

const HomePage = () => {

return (
      <Route path="/">
        {allPokemon && <AllPokemon allPokemon={allPokemon} />}
      </Route>
    </div>
)
}
```

And I put the mapped out list into this component. It's been shortened to what I think is the relevant parts. I get some data and display it

```
const ListPokemon = ({ individualPokemon }) => {
<Link to={`${pokeData.name}`}>name</Link>

some data

        <Route path="/:name" children={<SelectedPokemon />}></Route>

}
```

And then selectedPokemon component which I want to be the page that shows for the item clicked

```
const SelectedPokemon = (props) => {
  let { name } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> name: {name} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If its easier to just observe what is happening the link is on netlify for now: https://cool-react-pokedex.netlify.app/

Click the name hyperlink on any of the tiles to see what changes

Comment: so when click on any link for  any of the items, do you want to go a new page?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I'd like each tile to be a link for the respective item clicked

Comment: Have you tried to put all your routes inside the Switch and add the exact into the <Route>?

Comment: @Filipe Thanks for the comment. That got me down a new line of thinking and I changed it up just a bit. I read more of the React Router docs and it said to put the most specific Route at the top of the Switch and then got my problem taken care of.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the way you wrote your App route is wrong. I changed the format , added an exact to your route. You should also move your allPokemon data to this page

```
function App() {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <HomePage allPokemon={allPokemon}/>
          </Route>
           <Route exact path="/:id" render={({match}) => (
               <SelectedPokemon pokemon={pokemon.find(p => p.name === match.params.id)} />
            )} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

In the Route for the selected pokemon Route above, you look up the pokemon you want before you render it.
Secondly,  I dont why you wrapped the Homepage JSX with Route so it should be

```
const HomePage = ({allPokemon}) => {

return (

        allPokemon && <AllPokemon allPokemon={allPokemon} />
)
}
```

Lastly this should be your selectedPokemon

```
const SelectedPokemon = ({pokemon}) => {


  return (
    <div>
      <h2> name: {pokemon.name} </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```